# Laravel Relationship Can Not Get Data From Other Model

Tags: laravel, relationship

I've 2 tables (`students` and `accounts`).

```
students
+----+-----+------+
| id | nik | name |
+----+-----+------+

accounts
+----+-----+----------+----------+
| id | nik | username | password |
+----+-----+----------+----------+
```

When I want to get the account data from the relationship `$student->account->username` is running perfectly. But, when i try `$account->student->name`, i get an error :

> Trying to get property of non-object

I've check the data already and All were existed. What should I Do?

```
public function account()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Account::class, 'nik', 'nik');
}

public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'nik', 'nik');
}
```

Comment: @sta I've try it. But it produce the same error

Answer (score 0):

Change the method `belongsTo()` in the model `Account` to:

```
hasOne(Student::class, 'nik', 'nik')
```